# Different WCF endpoints, different method returns?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, soap

I am providing a WCf service from two different endpoints.

```
<service name="AB.Service.AccountService">
  <endpoint address="Account" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="regularBinding" contract="AB.Service.Library.IAccountService" />
  <endpoint address="M_Account" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mobileHttpBinding" contract="AB.Service.Library.IMAccountService" behaviorConfiguration="restBehaviour" />
  <endpoint name="mex" address="mex"  binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

Sample interfaces:

```
[StandardFaults]
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAccountService : INAccountService, IMAccountService
{
}

/// <summary>
/// This interface contains methods that are called from only web and desktop clients(only soap endpoint)
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract]
public interface INAccountService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<AccountContract> GetAccountInformation ( Session session );
}

/// <summary>
/// This interface contains methods that are called from both web and desktop and rest clients(soap and rest endpoint)
/// </summary>
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMAccountService
{
    [OperationContract,
    WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "GetUserType")]
    Task<UserType> GetUserType ( string logonName );

    [OperationContract,
    WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "LoginCheck")]
    bool LoginCheck ( Session session );
}
```

This way both soap and rest clients are able to use this service.

**What I am wondering is** can I change the return type in rest calls. Meaning that let's say in LoginCheck method it will return `true` in soap call but in rest call I will somehow wrap it in a generic class and it will return:

```
{
    success: true,
    message: "authorization successful"
}
```

**Why I am willing this is** because from some methods I throw exceptions defined in `[StandartFaults]` contract behaviour as part of the bussiness logic. But it is not really easy to handle such exceptions from the rest clients. Therefore I want an approach to provide such functionality.

**My alternative solution is** creating an isolated rest only service, and handling all exceptions in methods and returning them by wrapping them as I want. I am not really fond of this approach since it will reduce the reusability of the service methods, and equally the maintainability too.

Comment: Could you use some AOP framework to handle thrown exceptions and intercept the returns?

Comment: I haven't heard of AOP frameworks I guess, let me check

Comment: I couldn't found any useful clues. Can you elaborate?

Comment: AOP allows you to dynamically wire up method interceptors that act as wrapper functions. Essentially a proxy object is created that has registered your custom method in place of the original method. Your custom method invokes the original method (potentially in a try block) and gets its return value. You can then modify that value before you return it.